# How get the text element before angular directive has changed it content

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have a simple span element with some text. I want paste in my html just tag "span" with any text and directive "text-type". Every 100 ms a new symbol will appear. So, first, i have to save span text in some variable and then show text with my directive:

```
<span data-text-type>Just a text</span>
```

And I want to change text in my directive

```
app.directive('textType', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '{{newText}}',
    scope:{},
    link: function(scope, element) {
        var text = element.text().split(''); /*will be '{{newText}}', but not 'Just a text'*/

        scope.newText = '';

        (function fn () {
                if (text.length) {
                    scope.textStr += text.shift();
                    $timeout(fn, 100);
                }
            }());

    }
}
```

});

So, how can I save text before the directive will change it?

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: I try to explain in details :-)

Answer (score 0):

I find that it was needed use compile function that return link function, and change "scope:{}" to "scope:true" to use isolate scope for each element.

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:true,
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
        var string = element.text().split(''),
            max = string.length;



        element[0].innerHTML ='<span class="tt-text">{{textStr}}</span><span class="tt-heading">{{textHeading}}</span>';

        return function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var dur = 200;

            scope.textStr = '';
            scope.textHeading = string[0];

            (function fn() {
                if (string.length) {
                    head.stop().fadeOut(0).fadeIn(dur, function() {
                        scope.textStr += string.shift();
                        scope.textHeading = string[0];
                        scope.$apply();
                        fn();
                    });
                } else {
                    scope.textHeading = '';
                }
            }());
        }
    }
}
```